# Convert date to ISO 8601 in SQL Server FOR JSON PATH?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, iso8601

I am converting the data into json (using `FOR JSON PATH`) in SQL Server, one of the column in that data has a `datetime` datatype which I need to convert to ISO8601

Correct format: `2018-11-13T20:20:39+00:00`

When I tried `CONVERT(NVARCHAR(33), datetimecolumn, 127)`, the result is: `2019-10-24T12:35:12.870`

When I tried `TODATETIMEOFFSET(datetimecolumn, '+00:00')`, the result is:  `2015-03-31T00:00:00Z`

In both cases I am not getting `+00:00`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that SQL Server represents a zero offset or UTC time with `Z`.

If you were to run `SELECT TODATETIMEOFFSET(GETDATE(),60)`, which grabs the current time and applies a 1 hour offset, you would get the format you are expecting. However, I believe that `Z` denoting UTC is perfectly acceptable in ISO8601, but could be mistaken.

This command seems to output the JSON as expected.

`SELECT TODATETIMEOFFSET(GETDATE(),60) as T FOR JSON PATH`

If it is vital that the zero offset be represented as `00:00`, I believe you will be force to work with strings.

`select CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(33), getdate(), 127) as NVARCHAR(35)) + '+00:00' as T
FOR JSON PATH`

Answer (score 0):

JSON (as a data-interchange format) doesn't specify the format for date and time values. `FOR JSON` implicitly [converts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/how-for-json-converts-sql-server-data-types-to-json-data-types-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) date and time values to strings, but you can cast the `datetime` values in your statement with the appropriate type and style before using `FOR JSON`:

Statement:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(30), CONVERT(datetimeoffset(0), GETDATE()), 126) AS T
FOR JSON PATH
```

Result:

```
[{"T":"2020-04-22T08:02:58+00:00"}]
```

If you want to convert to a specific time zone, you may try to use `AT TIME ZONE`:

Statement:

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar, CONVERT(datetime2(0), GETDATE()) AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time', 126) AS T 
FOR JSON PATH
```

Result:

```
[{"T":"2020-04-24T08:33:49+02:00"}]
```